# Nginx override ssl_protocols directive

Tags: nginx

I have a global SSL Option file, that is included into every server block.

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1; # Requires nginx >= 1.1.0

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
ssl_session_tickets off; # Requires nginx >= 1.5.9

ssl_stapling on; # Requires nginx >= 1.3.7
ssl_stapling_verify on; # Requires nginx => 1.3.7

ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/dhparam4096.pem;

resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

gzip off;
```

So every server runs on TLSv1.2 but there is one server where I want to run with TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 as well.

But when I execute the config with either:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1;
include "above mentioned config file";
```

and

```
include "above mentioned config file";
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1;
```

But when running the command:

> nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443

Then it shows only TLSv1.2, but not TLSv1 nor TLSv1.1. Is there any way to override the ssl_protocols directive? If so, can I move the include into the http block?